# Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable while calling an api

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I'm trying to save a form which involves an API call but its throwing me an error that

> Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable.

when I call data=json.dump(dump) it throws the following error

```
 def getAttributes(self, jsonObj=False):
        attributes = vars(self)
        data = {var: value for var, value in attributes.items() if not var.startswith('_')}
        print(data, "data")
        if jsonObj:
            import json
            data = json.dumps(data)

        return data
```

p.s.: In print data statement it is returning me a dict.

Comment: Add your import json on top of the block

Comment: @user6837382 No difference, still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `value` variable is a byte sequence and not a string. You would need to transform it into Unicode.

```
data = {var: value.decode("utf-8") for var, value in attributes.items() if not var.startswith('_')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!! Just change return statement as 
return json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")

Comment: how did you write the code for receiver part??

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem it will decode text to utf-8

```
class BytesEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bytes):
            return obj.decode('utf-8')
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

data = json.dumps(data, cls=BytesEncoder)
```